# What happens to a Windows 7 workstation that acts as an RDP host?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I have observed that multiple things "change" on a PC or VM (either running Win7 Pro) when a machine rdp's to the system:

- There is a networking change of some kind. This might be a change in the network interfaces visible to user applications. This is discussed here: [How does acting as an RDP host affect UDP visibility/routing?](https://serverfault.com/q/692804/13716)
- The certificate store seems to change. (Well, specifically, the usb hardware token that is plugged in to the "host" is not accessible to the host OS when I am rdp'd in -- where it IS accessible when gotomypc is used to access the host.)

Is there a document that specifies all the "changes" that happen to the host when there is a remote session?